# Connect HTML page to Bootstrap (jumbotron)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to make a simple static web page with some Bootstrap functionality in it. I set up a LAMP server on an AWS ec2 instance to accomplish this.

To try some things out, I just wanted to use a jumbotron to make sure I was able to connect the bootstap library to my html page. I accomplished this at some point, but I stopped working on this and came back a few weeks later to continue. I picked up where I left off, with the same exact code, but this time, the jumbotron I had working was no longer present. Basically, the html page I made was a typical html page with normal fonts and no jumbotron effect. My code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Test</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--meta tag viewport purpose is to scale screen correctly-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet" >


</head>

<body>

<div class = "jumbotron">
    <div class = "container"> 
      <h1>Welcome to landing page!</h1>
     <p>This is an example for jumbotron.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>



</html>
```

I mentioned this is being done in an AWS ec2 instance. So assume that the path to my html file is /var/www/html. the html directory holds my .html file which is my static web page, and also holds the js,fonts,and css directories downloaded from bootstrap. So... once again, html directory contents are:

css  custom.css  fonts  js  Will.html

I'm confused as to how I left the code alone and after coming back a couple of weeks later, the jumbotron was no longer working. Initially there was a master bootstrap directory that held the css, fonts, and js directories, but I just got rid of that master directory and put the three directories inside on the same level as the html page. That shouldn't matter though, I just changed the path to those directories. I updated my LAMP server on the aws ec2 instance, so maybe thats causing an issue. Not sure though, any help on how to get this jumbotron working would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**try this**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Test</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<!--meta tag viewport purpose is to scale screen correctly-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-cale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet" >


</head>

<body>

<div class = "jumbotron">
    <div class = "container"> 
      <h1>Welcome to landing page!</h1>
     <p>This is an example for jumbotron.</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```